# Função Javascript - ajuda

Tags: javascript, funções

alguém me ajuda nessa atividade, não entendi function e não entra na cabeça, ainda não vi uma boa explicação.

Agora pedimos que você declare uma função chamada triploDaSoma() que recebe dois parâmetros. Então você tem que adicionar ambos e retornar três vezes o valor do resultado da soma dos dois parâmetros . Para fazer isso, você já conta (mesmo que não veja declarado) com a função triplo, que recebe um parâmetro e retorna o valor dele multiplicado por três.

Tentei fazer assim.

```
function triploDaSoma(num1, num2){
        function triplo(num1, num2){
            var resultado1 = somar(3, 2) * 3;
        return resultado1;
        }
        var resultado = somar(4, 5) * 3;
        return resultado;
}
```

mas vem o erro dizendo que está faltando:
Erros:

> Você deve utilizar a função triplo() dentro de triploDaSoma A execução
>   da função triploDaSoma(3,2) deve retornar o valor 15 A execução da
>   função triploDaSoma(4,5) deve retornar o valor 27

Sinceramente se eu não aprender function eu desisto de javascript.

Comment: Qual a sua dúvida?

Comment: Poderia mostrar o que tentou? Qual linguagem está utilizando? Este guia pode te ajudar a melhorar esta pergunta. https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-nÃo-fazer-perguntas

Comment: não entendi como fazer mal uma função e tenho que criar uma outra dentro, te juro já vi tantos vídeos e já li tanto sobre o assunto mais ainda não entrou na cabeça...

Comment: tentnei fazer assim: 
function triploDaSoma(num1, num2){
        function triplo(num1, num2){
            var resultado1 = somar(3, 2) * 3;
        return resultado1;
        }
        var resultado = somar(4, 5) * 3;
        return resultado;
}

Comment: sempre diz que está errado.
Você deve utilizar a função triplo() dentro de triploDaSoma
A execução da função triploDaSoma(3,2) deve retornar o valor 15
A execução da função triploDaSoma(4,5) deve retornar o valor 27

Comment: Edita a sua pergunta com esse código e explica por que tu tentou isso na pergunta, porque a pergunta não está muito clara :/

Comment: Lendo o erro, parece que você utiliza uma plataforma de exercícios e ela quer que tu use a função `triplo` pra fazer a multiplicação

Comment: sim, é do Santander Coder, uma bolsa para formação de devs. E eu estou na primeira semana de eliminação...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo que entendi do enunciado, não é para você criar a função `triplo`, é para você considerar que ela já existe e utiliza-la.

Supondo que essa seja a função triplo:

```
function triplo(valor) {
    return valor * 3;
}
```

Seu trabalho seria invoca-la dentro da função `triploDaSoma`:

```
function triploDaSoma(a, b) {
    var soma = a + b;
    var resultado = triplo(soma);
    return resultado;
}
```

Comment: cara que visão, copiei desse jeito e colei deu certo... cara que nívelcomo que consegue ser assim? parabéns pelo seu conhecimento e obrigado...