# Funções em JavaScript: Uma função dentro da outra

Tags: javascript, funções

1 - Tenho que criar a duas funções uma dentro da outra.
2 - A primeira função tem dois parametros.
3 - A segunda função tem um parametro.
4 - Segui o enunciado do problema:
5 - Declare uma função chamada triploDaSoma() que recebe dois parâmetros. Então você tem que adicionar ambos e retornar três vezes o valor do resultado da soma dos dois parâmetros.

Para fazer isso, você já conta (mesmo que não veja declarado) com a função triplo, que recebe um parâmetro e retorna o valor dele multiplicado por três.
6 - Eu fiz dessa forma:

```
function triploDaSoma (num1,num2) funcaotriplo(num3) {
  funcaotriplo = triploDaSoma (num1+num2);
  return funcaotriplo * 3;
}
triploDaSoma (3,2);
```

7 - Esse é o erro que aparece:

> Unexpected identifier

Comment: Veja se [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452905/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-javascript-ajuda) te ajuda.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro de tudo sim você pode declarar em javascript uma função dentro da outra.

Esse tipo de declaração chama-se de [Função Aninhada](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Fun%C3%A7%C3%B5es) e inicialmente é acessível apenas ao escopo que a contém, mas sua referência pode ser retornada para outro escopo.

É um [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) pois carrega consigo o escopo ao qual foi criada, mesmo que seus símbolos não sejam usados.

E é declarada como uma função normal só que dentro de outra função.

```js
//Função encapsuladora que retora o triplo da some de dois números.
function triploDaSoma(a, b) {
  //Função aninhada que retorna o triplo de um número.
  function triplo(x) {
    return 3 * x;
  }
  //Retorna o triplo da soma de a com b usando a função aninhada.
  return triplo(a + b);
}

console.log(triploDaSoma(3, 2));
```

Mas esse código serve somente como exercício pois faz exatamente o mesmo que esse mais simples:

```js
function triploDaSoma(a, b) {
  return 3 * (a + b);
}
console.log(triploDaSoma(3, 2));
```

Comment: Olá Augusto, seu raciocínio lógico resolveu o problema. Fiz alguns pequenos ajustes: tiplo (triplo) e ao invés de (a,b) (x) utilizei (num1,num2) (num3) pra mim fica mais fácil assim kkkk. MUITO OBRIGADO !!!

Answer (score 1):

Seu problema pode ser resolvido com uma das soluções abaixo

```js
/*
*Crio a função com três parametros 
*sendo que num3 sera o mutiplicador
*num1 e num2 serão somados
*/
function triploDaSoma(num1,num2, num3){
  let soma = num1+num2;
  //a função triplo retorna o triplo e esta só existira aqui
  function triplo(){
    //aqui é realizada a multiplicação
    //Repare que o return só vale para a função triplo
    return soma*num3
  }
  //retorno o resultado da função triploDaSoma
  return triplo();
}

console.log(triploDaSoma(3,2, 3));
//->15 //ja que 3+2==5*3==15
```

se me permitir eu escreveria este trecho de código da seguinte forma

```js
/*
*Renomeio a função para espreçar o que realmente ela esta fazendo
*/
function soma(num1,num2){
  //variavel que guardará o seu resultado
  let soma = num1+num2;
  //não recebe parametro já que seu objetivo é triplicar. mais nada impede
  function triplo(){
    return soma*3;
  }
  
  return {
    soma,
    triplo
  }
}
var somaDeFora = soma(3,2);
//então se quiser a soma
console.log(somaDeFora.soma);
//->5

//e se quiser o triplo
console.log(somaDeFora.triplo());
//->15
```

espero ter ajudado abraços...